# AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from view, but received `<class 'NoneType'>`

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following model -

```
class Userdetails(models.Model):

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
userno = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True
```

And following View -

```
 @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def useroptions(request):        # to create new user
        if request.method == 'GET':
            names = Userdetails.objects.values("name","userno","id")
            return Response(names)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            count = Userdetails.objects.count()
            serializer = userdetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
            usernos = Userdetails.objects.values("userno")
            names = Userdetails.objects.values("name")
            list_of_names = []
            for ele in names:
                list_of_names.append(ele["name"])

            list_of_usernos = []
            for ele in usernos:
                list_of_usernos.append(ele["userno"])
```

This gives me this error on CMD -

```
Internal Server Error: /view/pardel/2/multiuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 507, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 422, in finalize_response
    % type(response)
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[13/Feb/2020 08:09:14] "POST /view/pardel/2/multiuser HTTP/1.1" 500 17234
```

I am not getting the reason for this error and Please me to sort this error out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning `http` response object for `POST` request. From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects):

> Each view you write is responsible for instantiating, populating, and
>   returning an HttpResponse.

change your view to return http response for post request.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def useroptions(request):        # to create new user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        names = Userdetails.objects.values("name","userno","id")
        return Response(names)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        count = Userdetails.objects.count()
        serializer = userdetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        usernos = Userdetails.objects.values("userno")
        names = Userdetails.objects.values("name")
        list_of_names = []
        for ele in names:
            list_of_names.append(ele["name"])

        list_of_usernos = []
        for ele in usernos:
            list_of_usernos.append(ele["userno"])
        context = {'data': serializer.data, 'names': list_of_names, 'usernos': list_of_usernos} # change it as per your requirement
        return Response(context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are not returning from your view.

Code should be like this.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def useroptions(request):        # to create new user
        if request.method == 'GET':
            names = Userdetails.objects.values("name","userno","id")
            return Response(names)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            count = Userdetails.objects.count()
            serializer = userdetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
            usernos = Userdetails.objects.values("userno")
            names = Userdetails.objects.values("name")
            list_of_names = []
            for ele in names:
                list_of_names.append(ele["name"])

            list_of_usernos = []
            for ele in usernos:
                list_of_usernos.append(ele["userno"])

            response_dict = {}
            # update response_dict with whatever you want to send in response
            return Response(response_dict)
```